Electroetching Stainless Steel
I attempted to electroetch some stainless steel with sodium chloride. The solution became very turbid as something was falling out of solution. I believe I was consuming the electrolyte and making some sort of precipitate. I have to remove a large amount of steel, so I would prefer that the material lost from the anode, end up plating the cathode, rather than falling out of solution and consuming my electrolyte.
Is there a better electrolyte I could use? I was thinking something like sodium sulfate. I have only a little knowledge in chemistry from my college days, but I assume the sodium will act as a spectator ion like it does with sodium chloride.

First of all, doing this sort of thing with stainless alloys can release chromium, which is most definitely toxic, so take precautions. Secondly, my suggestion is to keep using the sodium chloride, but to add an acid at a concentration that will not immediately damage the un-etched surface. Explanation: The turbidity you observe is metal atoms being torn off the surface of the steel, which initially will have a greenish color, but will eventually react with dissolved oxygen or water molecules, forming iron oxide or hydroxide - rust, essentially. The rust is insoluble in water, so clouds up the solution and will not plate the cathode. Adding an acid may prevent this - Iron oxide and hydroxide are slightly alkaline, so will react with the acid to form a water-soluble iron salt, which will turn the solution orange-brown without fouling it up and which will plate onto the cathode.

Excellent. I will give it a shot. As for safety, even if the reaction is supposed to be benign I take the same amount of precautions. There are too many ways to mess up a reaction and get unexpected results.
